# How to find the new center of an UIImageView after scaling?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, imageview

I am creating an app where the user can add an image to a "canvas" and resize and move the image around using pinch and pan gesture recognizers.  The image view is a custom one I created using this article:
[Bezier Paths and Gesture Recognizers](https://www.weheartswift.com/bezier-paths-gesture-recognizers/)

This works really nicely.  The image resizes and moves very smoothly.  I can capture the center and the size of the image after the pan and pinch gestures.  The problem is that after I save the size and coordinates of the image it isn't respecting those when I load it back into the "canvas".  It is as if the center is offset by "X" number of pixels.

Here is my code for making the resizable and movable image view:

‘’’

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class MovableImage: UIImageView {
    let size: CGFloat = 150.0
    var imageMovedHandler:((_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> ())?
    var imageDeletedHandler:((_ delete: Bool) -> ())?
    var longPressHandler:((_ selected: Bool) -> ())?
    var imageSizeChangedHandler:((_ newImageView: MovableImage) -> ())?
    let deleteButton = UIButton(type: .close)

    init(origin: CGPoint) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: origin.x, y: origin.y, width: size, height: size)) //

        debugCenterDot()
        initGestureRecognizers()
    }

//added a dot to try and understand what is happening with the "center" of the imageview, but it didn't show in the center of the imageview
    func debugCenterDot() {
        let dot = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: self.center.x, y: self.center.y, width: 15, height: 15))
        let dotLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        dotLayer.path = dot.cgPath
        dotLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(dotLayer)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    internal func addButton() {
        deleteButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
        deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteSelf(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        deleteButton.frame = .zero //CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 15, height: 15)
        deleteButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(deleteButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            deleteButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15),
            deleteButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: deleteButton.heightAnchor),
            deleteButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            deleteButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8),
        ])


    }

    @objc func deleteSelf(sender: UIButton) {
        imageDeletedHandler?(true)
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func initGestureRecognizers() {
        let panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPan(panGR:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(panGR)

        let pinchGR = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPinch(pinchGR:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(pinchGR)

        let longPressGR = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPress(longPressGR:)))
        longPressGR.minimumPressDuration = 1
        addGestureRecognizer(longPressGR)

    }

    @objc func didLongPress(longPressGR: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        self.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(self)
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        addButton()
        longPressHandler?(true)
    }

    @objc func didPan(panGR: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        self.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(self)

        if self.layer.borderWidth == 2 {
            let translation = panGR.translation(in: self)

            print("BEFORE PAN: \(self.center)")

            self.center.x += translation.x
            self.center.y += translation.y

            print("AFTER PAN: \(self.center)")

            panGR.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)
            if panGR.state == .ended {
                imageMovedHandler?(self.center.x, self.center.y)
                self.layer.borderWidth = 0
                self.layer.borderColor = nil
                self.deleteButton.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func didPinch(pinchGR: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)

        if self.layer.borderWidth == 2 {
            let scale = pinchGR.scale

            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)

            if pinchGR.state == .ended {
                imageSizeChangedHandler?(self)
            }
        }
    }

    func scaleOf(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> CGPoint {
        let xscale = sqrt(transform.a * transform.a + transform.c * transform.c)
        let yscale = sqrt(transform.b * transform.b + transform.d * transform.d)

        return CGPoint(x: xscale, y: yscale)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

‘’’

And here is how I am loading it back into the "canvas" and saving it back to CoreData (save functions in closures near the bottom of the load function):

'''

```
    func loadImages(new: Bool, enableInteraction: Bool) {
            let pagePhotos = LoadPagePhotos()
            var pageImages: [NSManagedObject] = []
            var x: CGFloat?
            var y: CGFloat?
            var width: CGFloat?
            var height: CGFloat?
            var image: UIImage?

            if isYear {
                pageImages = pagePhotos.resetYearPhotosPositions(journalName: journalName, yearPosition: yearPosition)
            } else {
                pageImages = pagePhotos.resetPhotosPositions(journalName: journalName, monthName: monthName, weekPosition: positionWeek)
            }

            scrollView.mainView.newImages.forEach { i in
                i.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            scrollView.mainView.newImages.removeAll()

            if pageImages.count > 0 {
                pageImages.forEach{ (photo) in
                    x = CGFloat((photo.value(forKey: "pageImageX") as? Float)!)
                    y = CGFloat((photo.value(forKey: "pageImageY") as? Float)!)
                    height = CGFloat((photo.value(forKey: "pageImageSizeHeight") as? Float)!)
                    width = CGFloat((photo.value(forKey: "pageImageSizeWidth") as? Float)!)
                    image = photo.value(forKey: "image") as? UIImage

                    let thisImage: MovableImage = MovableImage(origin: CGPoint.zero)
                    thisImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    thisImage.center = CGPoint(x: x!, y: y!)
                    thisImage.image = image!
                    thisImage.frame.size.height = height!
                    thisImage.frame.size.width = width!

                    scrollView.mainView.addSubview(thisImage)
                    scrollView.mainView.newImages.append(thisImage)
                    if enableInteraction {
                        thisImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    } else {
                        thisImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                    }
                    thisImage.layer.zPosition = 1
                    thisImage.layer.borderWidth = 0

                    if new {
                        imageOptionsMenuView.isHidden = false
                    } else {
                        imageOptionsMenuView.isHidden = true
                    }
                    movableImage = thisImage
//for clarity sake I moved the save functions to separate block here in stack overflow so it is easier to read
            }

        }
```

'''

The closures "imageMovedHandler" and "imageSizeChangedHandler" are used   to detect when moving and resizing is done and I save the image to CoreData.  Here they are:

'''

```
if movableImage != nil {                        


movableImage?.imageMovedHandler = { [unowned self] (x, y) in
                    if self.isYear {
                        if self.scrollView.mainView.newImages.count > 0 {
                            for (idx, i) in self.scrollView.mainView.newImages.enumerated() {
                                if i.layer.borderWidth == 2 {
                                    let id = idx + 1
                                    _ = LoadPagePhotos().updateYearPhoto(journalName: self.journalName, yearPosition: self.yearPosition, pageImageId: id, imageHeight: Float(i.frame.size.height), imageWidth: Float(i.frame.size.width), imageX: Float(i.center.x), imageY: Float(i.center.y), pagePhoto: i.image!, photoPath: nil)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if self.scrollView.mainView.newImages.count > 0 {
                            for (idx, i) in self.scrollView.mainView.newImages.enumerated() {
                                if i.layer.borderWidth == 2 {
                                    let id = idx + 1
                                    _ = LoadPagePhotos().updatePhoto(journalName: self.journalName, monthName: self.monthName, weekPosition: self.positionWeek, pageImageId: id, imageHeight: Float(i.frame.size.height), imageWidth: Float(i.frame.size.width), imageX: Float(i.center.x), imageY: Float(i.center.y), pagePhoto: i.image!, photoPath: nil)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.loadImages(new: false, enableInteraction: true)
                }

    movableImage?.imageSizeChangedHandler = { [unowned self] (newImageView) in
                                var id = 0
                                var img = 0
                                if self.isYear {
                                    if self.scrollView.mainView.newImages.count > 0 {

                                    for (idx, i) in self.scrollView.mainView.newImages.enumerated() {
                                        if i.layer.borderWidth == 2 {
                                            id = idx + 1
                                            img = idx
                                        }
                                    }
                                    self.scrollView.mainView.newImages[img] = newImageView                                
                                    _ = LoadPagePhotos().updateYearPhoto(journalName: self.journalName, yearPosition: self.yearPosition, pageImageId: id, imageHeight: Float(newImageView.frame.size.height), imageWidth: Float(newImageView.frame.size.width), imageX: Float(newImageView.center.x), imageY: Float(newImageView.center.y), pagePhoto: newImageView.image!, photoPath: nil)
                                }
                            } else {
                                if self.scrollView.mainView.newImages.count > 0 {
                                    for (idx, i) in self.scrollView.mainView.newImages.enumerated() {
                                        if i.layer.borderWidth == 2 {
                                            id = idx + 1
                                            img = idx
                                        }
                                    }
                                    self.scrollView.mainView.newImages[img] = newImageView
                                    _ = LoadPagePhotos().updatePhoto(journalName: self.journalName, monthName: self.monthName, weekPosition: self.positionWeek, pageImageId: id, imageHeight: Float(newImageView.frame.size.height), imageWidth: Float(newImageView.frame.size.width), imageX: Float(newImageView.center.x), imageY: Float(newImageView.center.y), pagePhoto: newImageView.image!, photoPath: nil)
                                }
                            }
                            self.loadImages(new: false, enableInteraction: true)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

'''

Here is an image of what is happening when I move the image around the canvas:
This first image shows where I stopped moving the image to:
[image: Moving, pan still happening]

This image shows where the image was loaded after saving the size and coordinates:
[image]

The desired outcome is:

- When pinching, panning, and saving the image and then loading, the image retains its current coordinates and size in the canvas.

**EDIT:**
It should also be noted that the offset of the image when moving it only happens after "scaling

Comment: What I would do is debug. Look to see if the values you are saving are the right values. If they are, look to see if the values you are restoring are those same values.

Comment: They are.  I have check that multiple times.  I wonder if some of my constraints might be wrong?  I will look at them more closely, since it seems like when bringing the image view back it is offset.

Comment: Well, you're supplying so much code I can't even tell what's relevant and what's not. I couldn't find the saving code at all.

Comment: @matt I just edited the post to help make it easier to see what the code is doing and where the save functions are.  They are in 2 closures at the bottom of the "loadImages" function.  These 2 closures detect panning and pinching to update the image position and size in the DB.